# Sylius, Customizing ProductAttributeValue

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have customized `ProductAttributeValue` but I don't know how to tell Sylius about my new customized model.
I tried this:

```
sylius_product:
    resources:
        product_attribute_value:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductAttributeValue
```

and get this error:
  **Unrecognized option "product_attribute_value" under "sylius_product.resources"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/8885):

```
sylius_attribute:
    resources:
        product:
            attribute_value:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductAttributeValue
```

Comment: If it works, you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer to let other visitors know this is the way to handle this way of extending.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add into `sylius_resource` group in config.yml:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        sylius.product_attribute_value:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductAttributeValue
```

Comment: The sylius_resource was indeed an improvement, but in total it doesn't solve the issue, see the answer below for a full working solution :)